# how can i use exceptions in uBlock Origin?

Tags: adblock

in [this article](https://help.eyeo.com/adblockplus/how-to-write-filters), i read a bit about using `~` to create exceptions in a filter rule for ad blockers.

now, i created a rule `||*.com^`, which in itself functions to block any .com domains.
however, i would like to add exceptions to this rule, let's say starting with `stackoverflow.com`.
to this end i have tried variants of `||*.com^|~stackoverflow.com`, tho seemingly to no avail - the rule would just break.

has anyone grasped how to apply exceptions to achieve something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to exclude domains from your filters, so you need to use the `domain=` filter option. [Specifying filter options](https://help.eyeo.com/adblockplus/how-to-write-filters#options):

> These options should be separated with a comma (,) after a dollar sign ($) at the end of the filter.

You failed to use the options separator character `$`. Your filter should be:

```
||com^$domain=~stackoverflow.com
```

Notice that I also corrected another mistake in your filter: `||` means *anchor to hostname label*. `*` is not a hostname label, so using `||` accomplish nothing when followed by a wildcard. Given what you want to achieve with your filter, you want to anchor to `com` hostname label, hence `||com` and the `^` ensure that this is the last label of the domain name.